# How to add a secondary flycheck checker to lsp-ui

Tags: flycheck, lsp, lsp-ui

Because the lsp package sets the default checker to `lsp` (chaining not supported) I am using [this WA](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/1762) to chain another checker to lsp:

```
(defvar-local my/flycheck-local-cache nil)

(defun my/flycheck-checker-get (fn checker property)
  (or (alist-get property (alist-get checker my/flycheck-local-cache))
      (funcall fn checker property))) 

(advice-add 'flycheck-checker-get :around 'my/flycheck-checker-get)

(add-hook 'lsp-managed-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when (derived-mode-p 'sh-mode)
              (setq my/flycheck-local-cache '((lsp . ((next-checkers . (c/c++-cppcheck)))))))))
```

The WA works good, the, `cppcheck` checker is ran after the `lsp` one and the cppcheck issues are shown in the buffer.

The problem is that in `lsp-ui-flycheck-list` and `lsp-treemacs-errors-list` only the errors from the `lsp` checker are shown. How can I add the errors from cppcheck to `lsp-ui` as well?